# What attack vectors does AWS SSE-S3 protect you against?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, encryption, amazon-s3

Reading into the various SSE options on S3, I'm can't understand the following:

What exactly does the SSE-S3 (fully-managed, transparent at-rest encryption) protect you against?

I can only think of a physical attack vector, where someone physically gets the HDDs used for S3 storage. In that case, why is this encryption optional? Shouldn't it be a mandatory default, handled by AWS entirely for their own purposes?

In other words, what are the attack vectors that this particular solution helps to mitigate?

Thank you!

Comment: This appears to be less of a programming question than a security question. Consider asking it on [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: As I see it, SSE protects the medium itself (when reused or decommissioned). As well SSE protects resources against being accessed from roles not having access to KMS (e.g. another account even when having implicit permission)

Comment: `Shouldn't it be a mandatory default` - not always, sometimes you want to make the content accessible (e.g. accessing from different account doesn't work for SSE-protected resources)

Comment: Sometimes this is a regulatory or other compliance requirement. Also it's not just the live hdd in an actual server, consider backups for example, which can eventually turn out to be anywhere, or just components not having access to the keys (presumably stored in proper HSMs). OTOH this is an overhead, and also not possible in certain scenarios as others mentioned. Having said that, this *could* be the default, with an option to turn it off, but that would cost more for Amazon I guess, and many users don't care. :)

Comment: @gusto2 this question is specifically about [the `SSE-S3` variant of SSE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html), which doesn't require KMS setup or permissions, has no cross-account implications, and is fully transparent.

Comment: As suggested by @JamesKPolk, I've moved the question to StackExchange - Security. See [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201580/what-attack-vectors-does-aws-sse-s3-help-mitigate).

Comment: Answered [in StackExchange - Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201580/what-attack-vectors-does-aws-sse-s3-help-mitigate)